# Is the bivalence in classical logic just black or white thinking?

Tags: logic, thinking

So I was talking to my therapist and we started talking about how I accept classical logic. I explained that it relied on bivalence, the belief that propositions only have one truth value, they are true or false. (Forgive me if that not right. I haven't memorized this stuff so sorry.) Anyway, and he suggested that there may be a problem with accepting that propositions are binary, I think implying that it may be black or white thinking. What do you think about this guy's?

Comment: Bivalent ligic does not force us to live in a way or another... But the dichotomy true/false is quite basic since our infancy.

Comment: What does it mean to accept classical logic? There are philosophers who deftly defend the position propositions do not exist. However I know of none that would deny that, if they do exist, such and such classical logical argument necessarily is valid (or invalid), has bivalent truth values, etc.

Comment: (when I get you right,..)I think: the guy needs more therapy than you...but who loves not money, joy, vacation?;)

Comment: "The bivalence in classical logic is just." (confused therapists/animals should not use logical propositions (like  "or, and, when, if, then, not"(!))

Comment: ask him, whether (y/n) he knows what "honesty" is! If he knows what "honesty" is, he will give you clear and short answer: "yes" ...if not: start recording! :)

Comment: Wouldn't any yes/no answer to your question also be "just black or white thinking"?

Comment: I prefer red / green thinking, but some people are blind to that.

Comment: "Absolutes are always inherently false "

Answer (score 14):

By definition, boolean logic deals with exact, defined, black-or-white, true-or-false propositions. But that's only one form of logic. A number of philosophers and researchers have been bothered by the inability of boolean logic to handle shades of gray, thus leading to the development of "modal logics" (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/).

Boolean logic has proven useful for a variety of real-world uses, such as programming computers... but organizing your life isn't one of them. Logics are neither belief systems, nor heuristics for everyday living. It is well-established that they neither model the world perfectly, nor capture the nuances of informal language. Therefore you should feel free to open your mind to nonbinary thinking without fearing that it will prevent you from being a logical or rational person.

Comment: +1, see also probability as logic.

Comment: 'Nonbinary' seems to be the big thing these days. I prefer avoiding the whole issue, with nonduality.

Comment: @ScottRowe Unfortunately, [that term is overloaded, too](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dualism/).

Answer (score 7):

Most statements you encounter in real life don't have black and white truth values. Consider the following examples...

Golf is better than soccer.

Fats are bad for you.

Poor people shouldn't pay any tax.

You shouldn't give in to blackmailers.

If you take the view that those statements are either definitely right or definitely wrong then your thinking is too blunt. Whether golf is better than soccer depends on what you mean by better. Some fats might be bad for you, but some might be good for you. What do you mean by a poor person? Where do you draw the line between poor and not poor? Surely there are circumstances in which you should give in to blackmailers?

Some statements are indeed inherently binary. The trick is being able to distinguish between those that are and those that are not and process them accordingly.

Comment: I largely agree with you but let me play the *advocatus diaboli* for a second: One *could* argue that the questions are undecidable because they are not specific enough. "Golf is better for all/some/no people than soccer", "All/no/some fats are bad for you" and "You should never/always give in to blackmailers" are all decidable. "[All] Poor people shouldn't pay any tax" is probably decidable but it is a hard problem, and also lacks a metric. Is "no black and white" only true for underspecified questions?

Comment: Also, logic tends to deal with well-defined sets, so that for a set X and an object x, either x is in X or x is not in X. But in real-life we tend to almost-only use sets with blurry boundaries. When we write law we usually fix arbitrary boundaries (such as "above 18 you're an adult, below 18 you're not an adult") but except for these legal arbitrary definitions, everything is blurry. Where is the limit between red and orange? Where is the limit between a coat and a jacket? Thinking in black and white tends to force us to misclassify things (or people) that are close to a boundary.

Comment: And of course the "modelisation process", that allows us to turn real-world situations into logical propositions, is always going to be somewhat imperfect, so making hard black-and-white judgement on logical propositions and then applying these judgements to the real world is dangerous.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The problem is that real world issues are generally not amenable to being stated specifically enough that we can apply classic logic to them. Life is squishy.

Comment: @Barmar Not sure. For example, Marco's examples can be trivially transformed into decidable questions. (But I did note that the result is sometimes uninteresting -- many questions that contain "all", "no-one" or "some" qualifiers are trivially true or false. Often what we ask is "for most", or "for a significant minority", which is harder to answer (but not logically impossible!). Many interesting questions inviting debate probably lack defined metrics, as in "would the net effect of policy xy be positive".)

Comment: @Stef But grey and gray thinking is just so depressing! Although if you have *enough* shades it can be fun... 50 should do it.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica when you say transformed, what you mean is ignored. My point is not that it is impossible to have black and white statements- 'golfballs are smaller than footballs' is one- but that many everyday statements are not, and to 'transform' the latter into the former is missing the point.

Comment: @MarcoOcram Asking "what exactly do you mean" is not exactly ignoring. My experience with many liberal arts proponents is -- with all due respect (read: I think they are idiots) that they cannot think straight. There is a reason they chose a soft subject over physics or math. Many philosophical questions dissolve if you realize they are artifacts from fuzzy natural language use. (There is a reason that math has its formulaic language and that many expert domains use a highly formalized version of natural language).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I will give you a well deserved +1 for that comment. I could not agree with you more (in relation that that point at least!).

Comment: @MarcoOcram But you also have a leg in both worlds ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Either you are right, and logical propositions may be deemed completely true, or verifiably false, or you are wrong, and every statement may not be so classified.

I think your statement is somewhat wrong, and here's why. First, some propositions are definitely true or false. If A implies B and B implies C, then A implies C. This statement may be evaluated with no questions as to its veracity, so, certainly some statements may be true or false.

Sometimes, however, a statement has some truth. For example, "I drink alcohol because I'm sad". This is certainly a reason to drink alcohol, but sometimes I'm thirsty and my brain remembers alcohol is a cold and refreshing liquid and not that it's also dehydrating. Sometimes, I want to celebrate. Sometimes I want myself or others to feel less weird. Is the statement true or false? Well, if you assume it's true because sometimes it is true, then it's clearly incomplete. If you assume it's false because it isn't always true, then you're definitely avoiding the fact that sometimes I drink because I'm sad. In point of fact, the veracity of this statement (from a classical logic perspective) is a trivially meaningless diversion from the actual conversation about how much alcohol I drink and the effects it has on my life.

For what it's worth, somebody is paying your shrink about $100 per hour whereas these internetizens have neither credentials nor renumeration beyond internet points. Perhaps, you should give the professional the benefit of your classically trained mind's doubt and try to understand where they are going even if their vehicle wouldn't otherwise be allowed on your roads.

Comment: There is very little evidence in psychology, and of the little that there is, much is [wrong or even fraudulent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_crisis). Doubt should be the default when they cannot be ignored.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica a link to the replication crisis - a problem endemic to much of the social sciences - constitutes "very little evidence" that one should doubt their psychologist. There are terrible shrinks, and there will continue to be as the field matures, but their number will hopefully decline. A psychologist suggesting that binary thinking creates blind-spots sounds like they're on the right track though. Incidentally, Philosophy doesn't have a replication crisis because isn't even science.

Comment: Oh, wow. I said social sciences, but it looks like it's a problem endemic to science in general. I want to say that a trained x will know more than an un-trained x, but at this stage, we really can't be sure of that, so ... Binary thinking clearly won't get us out of this rabbit-hole

Comment: "Either you are right ... or you are wrong ...". Sounds like black or white thinking to me. This is actually [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question), because to propose that one of these two options must be true presupposes the conclusion, i.e. that every claim is either true or false.

Comment: @kaya3 Apparently my sense of humor is rather poor. Very good observation.